# ODP.Net Managed API - Array Binding with strings > 1000 characters

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, odp.net-managed

When using the ODP.Net managed API, when using array binding to insert data into a column of type VARCHAR2(4000), and a string length of a row value in our array is greater than 1000 characters, the following exception is thrown:

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO STAGING(\"COLUMN1\") VALUES (:COLUMN1)";

using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = dt.Rows.Count;

    var p = new OracleParameter { ParameterName = parameterName.ToUpper() };
    p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    p.Value = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => (!c.IsNull(fieldName) ? c.Field<T>(fieldName) : default(T))).ToArray();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

We currently define our parameters as:

```
p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
```

I tried to use this instead, but still run into the same issue:

```
p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
```

Also tried to set a size on the length of the Varchar2 as follows, but still have the same issue.

```
p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
p.Size = 4000;
```

Also tried this, with no luck:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO STAGING(\"COLUMN1\") VALUES (CAST(:COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR2(4000))";
```

Any ideas?

This appears to be a similiar issue: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3649551

**Update**
I suspected that maybe there was some sort of character set issue, which made the length longer than expected, so to rule this out, I reduced the column length of the table that we're trying to insert data into down to VARCHAR2(1000), assuming that this would make the maximum allowable character length to be 250 - this is not the case though. The maximum that is working before this exception is thrown is still 1000.

**Update 2**
I've found an oracle patch which may resolve this issue. I will try and get this patch and verify. https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?patchId=20361140&requestId=18735492

**Update 3**
The oracle patch didn't fix the issue for me. I tried to iterate through all of the parameter bind statuses, but they all indicate a success.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    foreach (OracleParameter p in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        foreach (var s in p.ArrayBindStatus)
        {
            if (s != OracleParameterStatus.Success)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 4**
Seems that this is a bug in the Oracle Managed API, here's a sample class that can reproduce the issue.

```
namespace OracleBindError
{
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testTable = "BIND_TEST_TABLE";
            string connString = "[conn string here]";

            string dropTable =
@"DECLARE pEXISTS NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO pEXISTS FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + testTable + @"';

  IF(pEXISTS > 0) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE " + testTable + @"';
  END IF;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE " + testTable + @" (COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(4000), COLUMN2 VARCHAR2(4000))';
END;";

            string[] greaterThanOneThousand = new string[] {
                        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkldfdffd",
            };

            string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO " + testTable + "(\"COLUMN1\",\"COLUMN2\") VALUES (:COLUMN1,:COLUMN2)";

            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                OracleCommand dropCmd = new OracleCommand(dropTable, conn);
                dropCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = insertStatement;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.BindByName = true;
                    cmd.ArrayBindCount = greaterThanOneThousand.Length;

                    var p = new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "COLUMN1" };
                    p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                    p.Value = greaterThanOneThousand.ToArray();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

                    var p2 = new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "COLUMN2" };
                    p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                    p2.Value = new string[] { null };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Found work-around**
**If I change the OracleDbType from Varchar2 to NVarchar2 in my parameters it works.**

```
var p = new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "COLUMN1" };
p.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
p.Value = greaterThanOneThousand.ToArray();
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

var p2 = new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "COLUMN2" };
p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
p2.Value = new string[] { " " };
cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
```

**Work-Around**
The work-around is to use NVARCHAR2 in the parameter on the .net side.

Comment: I am assuming that the base table does not use a LONG datatype and your array type is a string?

Comment: Base table column is of type VARCHAR2(4000).

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning array of type "T" into value. Whereas, the database expects it to be VARCHAR2(4000), which is equivalent to string. Try converting the value to string.

Comment: T in this case is of type string. The value in the parameter in a string array.